# jQuery can't be accessed by other .js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Here is a html page:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="background.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is background.js:

```
alert("Alert1!");
var test = jQuery.trim(" Words and / { objects & things");
alert("Alert2!");
```

Alert1 works, but alert2 never plays. If i remove the jQuery then it works.  I've tried the background.js file in both the header and body. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download `jquery.js` from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js and put it inline to your extension directory and refer it inline as shown here.

## Root Cause

External reference to files is not supported in Chrome Extensions.

## Working Version

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="background.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

## Edit 1

## Working Version

#### manifest.json

Registered both Jquery and Your code to `manifest file`.

```
{
    "name": "Jquery In Background",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14438044/jquery-cant-be-accessed-by-other-js-file",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "jquery.js",
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

#### background.js

Your code as before

```
alert("Alert1!");
var test = jQuery.trim(" Words and / { objects & things");
alert("Alert2!" + test);
```

Comment: I've already tried that actually and it has no effect:

<script src="vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: @Slappybag: What is the HTML Page you are referring to ? Can you share any relevant code if there is any?

Comment: Well the only other aspect I can add is that its being  referenced from a manifest.json. Otherwise I have stripped everything out and it is as presented.

`code`"background": {"page": [ background.html" ]},

Comment: @Slappybag: As i see you want jquery in your `background page` isn't?

Comment: Exactly, jQuery doesn't seem to be loading in background.js at all.

Comment: @Slappybag:Check My **EDIT 1**, you can add jquery as shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks man much obliged, I'll have to check this though when back at the home-office. Cheers.

Comment: This doesn't actually work, the jquery is still killing the script =/

Comment: Note: I completed replaced my code with yours. Mine was exactly the same but alert2 doesn't show. >_<

Comment: @Slappybag: It does show, there is some thing you are missing here.. post all code you are using ..

Answer (score 1):

I am able to alert the trimmed value with the following manifest and code.

Manifest

```
{
  "name": "Tester",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background":{
    "page":"background.html",
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

background.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="background.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
var test = jQuery.trim(" Words and / { objects & things");
alert(test);
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, the jquery is still killing the script =/

Comment: No, this actually DOES work. Something you are doing is killing the script.